# In XAML - How to repeat a shape x number of times, where x is an int property in a class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an integer MyProperty in MyClass and I would like to bind the number of ellipses shown in my view to that property:

```
<StackPanel>
... Show MyProperty number of ellipses ...

</StackPanel>
```

I have had a look at ItemsControl but the ItemsSource requires a collection.

Is there a way of repeating a number of shapes by binding to a simple property?
(Using XAML)

Thanks for reading,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot repeat a shape X times as you described, but what you can do - is to write a ValueConverter that would convert number X into an enumeration of X items.

Comment: Yeah, it ca njust return `Enumerable.Range(1, X)`

Comment: Thanks Denis, are you suggesting I use this ValueConverter via the ItemsSource binding of an ItemsControl?

Comment: Checked, this works fine. Thanks also to Gabe, I used that line.